# If statement, differential equation

Tags: differential-equations

I've got problem with If statement. It doesn't work. I've never used Mathematica before, probably it's a problem with syntax.

```
wynik1 = 0
For[u = 0, u <= 1, u = u + 0.1, 
 s = NDSolve[{x1'[t] == u*(10*x2[t] - x1[t]), x1[0] == 1, 
    x2'[t] == u*(x1[t] - 10*x2[t]) - (1 - u)*x2[t], x2[0] == 0}, {x1, 
    x2}, {t, 0, 1}];
 wynik = 1 - Evaluate[{x1[1] /. s} + {x2[1] /. s}];
 If[wynik > wynik1, wynik1 = wynik; Print[wynik1]]]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are only interested in the values of your functions *evaluated at a specific point*, you may want to use [`ParametricNDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolveValue.html) to approach your problem in a more direct way

First generate an implicit family of solutions of your differential system returning the values of `x1[1]` and `x2[1]` as a function of your parameter `u`:

```
Clear[u, x1, x2, t]
solutions = ParametricNDSolveValue[
   {
    x1'[t] == u*(10*x2[t] - x1[t]), x1[0] == 1, 
    x2'[t] == u*(x1[t] - 10*x2[t]) - (1 - u)*x2[t], x2[0] == 0
   },
   {x1[1], x2[1]}, {t, 0, 1}, u
   ];
```

Then calculate all pairs of values of `x[1]` and `x[2]` for each value of $u$ of interest in the range $(0, 1)$:

```
valuesforu = solutions /@ Range[0, 1, 0.1]

(* Out: 
{{1., 0.}, {0.931991, 0.0426269}, {0.902059, 0.0618784}, {0.889307, 0.071569}, 
 {0.884889, 0.0771448}, {0.884867, 0.0808241}, {0.887377, 0.0835529}, {0.891474, 0.0857601}, 
 {0.896641, 0.0876553}, {0.902577, 0.0893498}, {0.909092, 0.0909076}}
*)
```

Finally, you seem to be interested in the maximum of the function `1 - x1[1] +x2[1]`, so we can calculate values of this function and separately find the highest one as follows:

```
1 - #1 + #2 & @@@ valuesforu
Max[%]

(* Out: {0., 0.110636, 0.15982, 0.182262, 0.192255, 0.195957, 0.196176, 0.194287, 
         0.191014, 0.186773, 0.181815} *)

(* Out: 0.196176 *)
```

Comment: That's exactly what I need. Thank you. 

One more question. What does ' & @@@' means?

Comment: @K.Kozieł **1)** `f @@@ expr` is shorthand for [`Apply[f, expr, {1}]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html), which replaces the heads at level 1 of `expr` by `f`. Take a look at the `Apply` entry here: [Animated *Mathematica* Functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/flash/). **2)** The `&` has to do with [defining a pure function](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html). Take a look at other examples of such possibly confusing shorthand here: [What the @#%^&*?! do all those funny signs mean?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/27951).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
wynik1 = 0;
For[u = 0, u <= 1, u = u + 0.1,
 s = NDSolve[{x1'[t] == u*(10*x2[t] - x1[t]), x1[0] == 1, 
    x2'[t] == u*(x1[t] - 10*x2[t]) - (1 - u)*x2[t], x2[0] == 0}, {x1, 
    x2}, {t, 0, 1}];
 wynik = First[1 - x1[1] + x2[1] /. s];
 (*Print[wynik];*)
 If[wynik > wynik1, wynik1 = wynik; Print[wynik1]];
 ]
wynik1
```